# Embed country in user model with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using Rails 4 and Mongoid. I have the following models:

```
class Country
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :iso
  field :name

  embedded_in :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email
  field :name

  embeds_one :country
end
```

On edit user view I want to place drop down with countries so selected country will be selected as embedded in user record. I tried to use something like this:

```
<%= f.select :country, Country.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c._id] }, :prompt => 'Please select' %>
```

But it doesn't look to be working:

```
undefined method `__metadata' for "5324c9f7416c65a032070000":String
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-16 16:31:32 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UzETkbI3MNGBJQg7IhzI6jD5dQCZrvjU0JAgkReTSak=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "birth_date"=>"", "gender"=>"", "marital_status"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>"5324c9f5416c65a032000000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `__metadata' for "5324c9f5416c65a032000000":String:
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:141:in `characterize_one'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/one.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:42:in `init'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/one.rb:19:in `initialize'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `new'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `create_relation'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in setter'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:140:in `without_autobuild'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:229:in `block in setter'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:141:in `block in process_relations'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:136:in `each_pair'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:136:in `process_relations'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:122:in `process_pending'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:29:in `process_attributes'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/document.rb:110:in `block in initialize'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in `_building'
   () Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-164755a9d038/lib/mongoid/document.rb:104:in `initialize'
  devise (3.2.3) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new'
  devise (3.2.3) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new_with_session'
  devise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:95:in `build_resource'
  devise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__4022758027926609887__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3804891227325973598__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of the error? Also, when exactly do you get the error, on form submission or while rendering edit view?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are not setting the country correctly in the user...

try adding the following to the user model
if you want to set the country in a normal mongoid way or with id..

```
  def country
    @country ||= Country.where(id: country_id).first
  end

  def country=(obj)
    case obj.class
    when String
      self.country_id = obj
      @country = Country.find(obj)
    when Country
      self.country_id = obj.id
      @country = obj
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'd actually create a different attribute for this than 'country' as this will get you into trouble when you actually try to set a country instance the 'normal' way.

Comment: i edited the answer to allow setting the country by only id or by the "normal way" try it and tell me if you encountered any errors. i;m using a similar way in a case i encountered.

Comment: country_id doesn't exist in your get function. Why not just make the get and set function for country_id and leave country alone?

Comment: i work with the `@country` in the set and get.. to simulate the mongoid getter and setter behaviour... so if you used `user.country` you actually get the country object not just the id... so `user.country.where(id: 'somevalue').exist?` would actually work like any other mongoid relation. so you won't even notice that this field has a custom setter and getter... it works the same way mongoid works

Comment: You are returning an instance in country(), not a relation, so you would just get undefined method 'where' on either the instance or nil:NilClass.

Comment: it's an embeds_one, embedded_in relation... this `user.country.where` won't  be valid (my mistake in the previous comment :D) ? PS i use the same code in almost the same case in my app and i never had a problems with it.